# Can I get device structure from major number and minor number

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to implement the linux security hook `security_inode_mknod`.There is a parameter `dev`, I want to use it to get the device structure and put this structure in to [`usb_deauthorize_device(struct usb_device *usb_dev)`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.1/source/drivers/usb/core/hub.c#L2517) and  [`ata_dev_disable(struct ata_device *dev)`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10/source/drivers/ata/libata-eh.c#L1345) to block usb device and sata device, 
Is this method feasible?  If not, can I use other parameters to get it?

```
 *  Check permissions when creating a special file (or a socket or a fifo
 *  file created via the mknod system call).  Note that if mknod operation
 *  is being done for a regular file, then the create hook will be called
 *  and not this hook.
 *  @dir contains the inode structure of parent of the new file.
 *  @dentry contains the dentry structure of the new file.
 *  @mode contains the mode of the new file.
 *  @dev contains the device number.
 *  Return 0 if permission is granted.
static inline int security_inode_mknod(struct inode *dir,
                    struct dentry *dentry,
                    int mode, dev_t dev)
```

Comment: Can you explain better what is the goal you are trying to achieve? I don't understand what is the link between `security_inode_mknod` and `usb_deauthorize_device` etc, they work on really different type of device.

Comment: @Claudio i just want to block usb device. I assume that `mknod` create the device node after usb device insertion, so i put the `usb_deauthorize_device` in `security_inode_mknod` . Was i wrong?